# How to configure settings to alter the default Panels that open on startup?

Tags: qgis

I want the "layers" panel to display automatically when I open any project.  I don't want to have to perform View --> Panels --> Check the Box every time I open QGIS.

How can I do this?

Comment: Which version do you use? in QGIS 2.18 there is no Panels in the View menu. In QGIS 2.18 click with the right mouse button in an empty toolbar area. Turn on the necessary panes. The panel settings are preserved leaving QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check `Settings | Customization` to see if `Docks | Layers` is active?

If it was inactive, please tick it On *(2)* or click on `[Reset]` button *(3)*.

[image]

I am least sure of this, because such an incident rarely happens. (This window is grayed out by a fail-safe `Enable customization` switch *(1)*.)